# Google Speech Recognition doesn't print the data as String

Tags: python, speech-recognition, speech-to-text, python-3.8

So, I wanted to write a program that recognizes the audio from the Microphone and prints it as a string. But Python didn't print the recorded audio as a string. I watched some tutorials and read some articles but nothing helped.
Can you help me?
This is my code:

```
import speech_recognition as sr
r = sr.Recognizer()

with sr.Microphone() as source:                
    audio = r.listen(source)                   

try:
    print("You said " + r.recognize_sphinx(audio))   
except LookupError:                          
    print("Could not understand audio")
```

Thanks!

Comment: `But Python didn't print the recorded audio as a string` well what did it do? Print an empty string? Are you 100% sure your audio input is working?

Comment: No, but I don't how I could fix this

Comment: I asked 3 separate questions and you just said "no", I have no idea what you're responding to.

Comment: It did nothing: no error and no reaction. By the no, but I don't know how to fix this I mean the audio input

Comment: I'd start by testing that your audio input is working elsewhere, and that your default audio input is the correct one.